Is VTube an actual social network in Japan, or is it a trope made up for animes?
In animes, I've seen several times characters mentioning "VTube" , a social network just like Youtube, but with a slightly different name. If I recall correctly, one anime I've seen it is in one episode of Kaii to Otome to Kamikakushi, I'm sure I've seen it in other animes I dont recall right now, and a new anime just appeared called VTuber Nandaga Haishin Kiri Wasuretara Densetsu ni Natteta , so that's another.
My question is, is this a real social network in Japan, and anime it's just reflecting japanese culture, or is it an anime trope made up to avoid having copyright issues with Youtube?

There is, as far as I can tell, no such social network. DenchiSoft has a software product called VTube Studio, but that's unrelated. Instead, it's likely that this is being used as a parody brand to avoid trademark issues (which, like copyrights, are a form of intellectual property, but are more relevant when talking about brand names). This is a very common occurence in anime and even live action, where characters will frequently eat at WcDonald's and do their homework on laptops with a Pineapple logo.

I think I've also seen Google being renamed in one anime

VTube is just using a virtual avatar on YouTube and other sites.
VTuber

A VTuber (Japanese: ブイチューバー, Hepburn: BuiChūbā) or virtual YouTuber
(バーチャルユーチューバー, bācharu YūChūbā) is an online entertainer who uses a
virtual avatar generated using computer graphics. Real-time motion
capture software or technology are often—but not always—used to
capture movement. The digital trend originated in Japan in the
mid-2010s, and has become an international online phenomenon in the
2020s.[1][2] A majority of VTubers are English and Japanese-speaking
YouTubers or live streamers who use avatar designs. By 2020, there
were more than 10,000 active VTubers.[3] Although the term is an
allusion to the video platform YouTube, they also use websites such as
Niconico, Twitch, Facebook, Twitter, and Bilibili.

